# How can I restore mysql db?

Tags: 16.04, mysql, mariadb

I have my own Ubuntu 16.04 server system and MySQLdb in it. And today, I installed MariaDB on the system without noticing installed Mysql. ( with "sudo apt-get install mariadb-server.." command )

I realized there is a mysql-server when finished installing mariadb. So, I removed mariadb with "sudo apt-get remove mariadb-server.." command.

And now, I can't access mysql db with error 2002.
( Naturally, I can't start mysql also. )

How can I fix this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you reinstall mysql-server after uninstalling mariadb? is it running (`systemctl status mysql.service`)

Comment: I reinstalled and finally restored my database with original physical files ( /var/lib/mysql ). Thanks :)